# Use Angular Flex-layout breakpoint aliases in my own scss files

Tags: angular, sass, angular-flex-layout

I'd like to use the breakpoint aliases defined in Angular Flex-layout in my own scss files and I don't know what to import. I don't see any `.scss` nor `.css` files in my `/node_modules/@angular/flex-layout` folder.

I hope it's possible, so if you could help me with that ;-)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to apply style depending on the size of the screen, flex-layout upgrades the default ngClass & ngStyle directives to make them work this way :

```
<div [ngClass.sm]="{'fxClass-sm': hasStyle}"></div>
```

or

```
<div [ngStyle.xs]="{'font-size.px': 10, color: 'blue'}"></div>
```

See this [page](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/API-Documentation#special-responsive-features).

Then you can add classes which can be fetched in you scss.